# 'Hope' vs. 'wish' in unlikely situations

Tags: word-usage

Although 'hope' and 'wish' have many different uses, I've seen the basic difference often summarized as: 'wish' is for imaginary, unlikely or impossible things, whereas 'hope' is for more likely or realistic things.

For example:

> I wish I was a billionaire (unlikely)
>
> I hope you get well soon (likely)

This distinction seems logical, but then I don't understand the following:

> I hope you win the lottery tonight (unlikely)
>
> I hope you rot in hell! (impossible ... I hope!)

Both scenarios seem highly unlikely, yet the grammar is acceptable.

Is there are a better distinction between 'hope' and 'wish' in this kind situation?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **wish** can be an idle expression of a desire that things could be different than they actually are *at the current time* - in other words, a [counterfactual](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/counterfactual?s=t):
 - "I wish I were a millionaire!"
 - "I wish I hadn't drunk those last five beers."
 - "I wish Grandma were still alive."

A wish can also be a type of prayer, sometimes barely religious and hardly conscious of being a prayer; this type of prayer is generally simply for the health or happiness of another:
 - "[We wish you a merry Christmas.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Wish_You_a_Merry_Christmas)"
 - "During his illness, his room was constantly full of [well-wishers](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-wisher)."

It can also be a more explicit form of what a Christian would call "pagan" and others would call "superstitious" prayer; the object of this type of wish is usually kept secret for magical reasons:
 - tossing a coin in a [well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishing_well)
 - breaking a [wishbone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furcula)

In fairy tales, one may meet magical beings ([djinni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn), [leprechauns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprechaun), [talking goldfish](http://www.storynory.com/2006/08/27/the-golden-fish/)) and be granted wishes; these are specific requests, granted immediately, and often with [cruel irony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey%27s_Paw).

**Hope**, on the other hand, deals with what is possible - now or in the future - without making a counterfactual change:
 - "I hope you feel better soon."
 - "I hope we get there in time."
Since this type of hope is essentially passive, it is often mocked: "Hope in one hand, and $#*& in the other - see which one fills up first!"

Hope can also deal with events and outcomes that are unknown to the speaker, and over which s/he has no control:
 - "I hope Jane got home safely."
 - "I hope Grandpa's in a better place now."

Hope can also be negative; the desire expressed does not have to be likely or even possible:
 - "I hope you die in a fire."
 - "I hope you rot in Hell."

Hope is also the belief - sometimes against all evidence - that things will be better in the future than they are now:
 - "I live in [hope](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07465b.htm) that I'll find my pet rock again someday."
 - "[Hope dies last](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/19459/)."
**[Despair](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04755a.htm)** is the absence or abandonment of this type of hope.

Answer (score 0):

[Hope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hope) is the **state** which promotes *the desire of positive outcomes* related to events and circumstances in one's life or in the world at large.

*Hope* is the **feeling** that what is wanted *can be had* or that events will turn out *for the best*.

*Hope* is the **act** of *looking forward* to something with desire and *reasonable confidence* or "feeling that something desired may happen".

Other definitions include: "to cherish a desire with anticipation"; "to desire with expectation of obtainment"; or "to expect with confidence".

Despair is often regarded as the opposite of hope.

*Hope* is one of the commonly used expressions of anger!